# Protractor AngularJS wait till element is displayed and do some actions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I must create a method which do some action while some element is not visible on the page. When it shown I end test.

```
this.waitHolidayInCalendarFunc = function () {
                return browser.wait(anyHolidayInCalendar.isDisplayed()
                    .then(nextWeekButton.click()));
            };
```

But there is error

> "failed:  fn is not a function"

I tried do method like this:

```
this.IsPresentHoliday = function () {
            browser.wait(function () {
                return holiday.isPresent();
            }, defaultDelay);
        };"
```

And in test I add 'while' like this

```
var clickNextWeek = new holidaycalendar.NavigateOnCalendarView();
while (clickNextWeek .IsPresentHoliday() == false ) clickNextWeek.GoNextWeek();
```

But method isPresent() return true (but element not present on the page) and test passed! Please, help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ExpectedConditions` along with `browser.wait` to make your scripts to wait for certain conditions. Try the below code.

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var waitTime = 5000; //5 secs
var elementToBeVisible = element(by.id("some-id"));
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(elementToBeVisible),waitTime);
```